# How does the ridge regressor in cross_val_score uses the alphas?

Tags: python, function, regression

I have below some code for a simple ridge regression algorithm. The point of the program is to check which value of the alpha is the best to use in this regression by calculating the cross val score for each alpha. The thing I don't understand is how does it select the alpha in the for section? I mean, I know it iterates over every alpha from that logspace but the ridge = Ridge(normalize=True) doesn't have any parameter of alpha, so why doesn't it just use the default one every time(alpha=1.0)? In the cross_val_score function it just calls the ridge regressor and doesn't specify the ridge.alpha variable defined earlier at all.

```
alpha_space = np.logspace(-4, 0, 50)
ridge_scores = []
ridge_scores_std = []

#Create a ridge regressor: ridge
ridge = Ridge(normalize=True)

# Compute scores over range of alphas
for alpha in alpha_space:

# Specify the alpha value to use: ridge.alpha
ridge.alpha = alpha

# Perform 10-fold CV: ridge_cv_scores
ridge_cv_scores = cross_val_score(ridge,X,y,cv=10)

# Append the mean of ridge_cv_scores to ridge_scores
ridge_scores.append(np.mean(ridge_cv_scores))

# Append the std of ridge_cv_scores to ridge_scores_std
ridge_scores_std.append(np.std(ridge_cv_scores))
```

Comment: is this supposed to be a working code? Can you set the indents correctly? But yes, you need to input the alpha

Comment: yes, this code actually works when I compile and run it, and it gives me different results for the different alpha, but i can't understand how.

Answer (score 0):

The reason lies within the following line of code:

```
# Specify the alpha value to use: ridge.alpha
ridge.alpha = alpha
```

The ridge instance, initialized by:

```
ridge = Ridge(normalize=True)
```

has an internal 'alpha' attribute, which you can set and change in different ways. One way is the one you seem to be familiar with, which is specifying the alpha *parameter* when starting Ridge, for example:

```
ridge1 = Ridge(alpha=0.5, normalize=True)
```

Another method, which is the one used in the code you posted, is to just initialize the ridge *without* specifying an alpha and just *setting/specifying* it later. How? Through the Ridge internal attribute called 'alpha'. And as you know, to access a class' attributes you use the dot notation.

So by doing:

```
ridge2 = Ridge(normalize=True)
ridge2.alpha = 0.5
```

you are achieving the same as with the ridge1 instance. That is how it works in the for loop. By setting a new value over ridge.alpha, the 'inner' alpha value for the ridge instance does in fact get changed.

I hope it helps, otherwise I can try to draw a diagram to clarify further.